# Vue.js v-for Index

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Just new to use Vue.js and I have a question:

I have a array to build a table.  If I double click the table row, the program will call a javascript function to get the selected item by its index.

```
<div id="vm-table">
    <table>
        <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" ondblclick="getItem('{{ index }}')">
            <td>{{ index }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.pk }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#vm-table",
        data: {
            items: []
        }
    });
</script>
```

I assume the array  "items" already contains a list of items.  In the above "tr" line it seems cannot get the "index" value and the value must be used in the inner "td" elements.  If I need to get the parameter of index how can I do?

Thanks,

Comment: instead of `ondblclick="getItem('{{ index }}')"` try `@dblclick="getItem(index)"`

Comment: Successed!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" @dblclick="getItem(index)">
        <td>{{ index }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
    </tr>
```